# manim error when doing the rendering LaTeX

Tags: manim

I have been having a problem creating a video to test manim

here is the [error of the console](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hqXCxY75HtHMn0gJ529eErP6WC3jpQi6/view?usp=sharing)

and here is the [error of MiKTeX](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cZ0eSLN3HS4_RIRpb3HkUIPkzRFbra2i/view?usp=sharing)

and here is [the code itself](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p3UVly-wRsFWxG4DGqiNKzgOItUCH1Yr/view?usp=sharing)

thank you in advanced! ^-^

Answer (score 0):

In Python strings, `\` is a special character which needs to be escaped if it should not be treated in this special way. This can be done by either writig a double backslash `backslash_string = "\\"`, or by using a raw string `backslash_string = r"\"`.

Take a look at [Manim's LaTeX tutorial](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/tutorials/using_text.html?highlight=raw%20string#text-with-latex) to see some examples of properly escaped TeX strings.